# regular expression of python

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling when writing regular expression in python.
For instance I get the following right

```
"GET /images/launch-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 220 1839
```

is matched by

```
"(\S+) (\S+)\s*(\S*)" (\d{3}) (\S+)
```

however I still need to include the following cases all together

1. `"GET /history/history.html          hqpao/hqpao_home.html
   HTTP/1.0" 200 1502`
2. `"GET /shuttle/missions/missions.html Shuttle Launches from
   Kennedy Space Center HTTP/1.0"200 8677`
3. `"GET /finger @net.com HTTP/1.0"404 -`

obviously I should change the **bold** part of the expression

```
"(\S+) (\S+)\s*(\S*)" (\d{3}) (\S+)
```

But how should I change it. I have one approach in mind which is change the **bold** part to

```
[\s |(\s*)(\S+) |(\S+)(12) |(\S+)]
```

where the 2nd, 3rd , 4th expression is the (1), (2), (3) extra cases I need to deal with.

But my expression do not work. What do I misunderstand about regular expression as I simply deal with it case by case.

Comment: Are the beginnings `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`  part of what you want to match or is that a numbered list of strings to match?

Comment: my regular expression have to include all (1), (2), (3) and the very beginning cases

Comment: Yes, but is the actual string to match in the (1) case `(1)"GET /history/history.html          hqpao/hqpao_home.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1502`, or is it just `"GET /history/history.html          hqpao/hqpao_home.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1502` and the (1) is just there to number it in your post here?

Comment: oh! It is just for numbering and not included in the requirement

Answer (score 1):

This Might be a bit messy but it works:

```
\"(\S+) (\S+[\s\w\.\@]*)\s*(\S*)\"\s?(\d{3})\s(\S+)*
```

You can play with it on Regexr. [Regexr Shared Link](http://regexr.com/42slu)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^"([^\s"]+)\s+([^\s"]+)(?:\s+([^"]+?))?\s+([A-Z]+/\d[\d.]*)"\s*(\d{3})\s*(\S+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HhlHkY/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line  (use `re.M` if you are reading the whole file into a variable, `f.read()`)
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `([^\s"]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and a double quotation mark
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([^\s"]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than whitespace and a double quotation mark
- `(?:\s+([^"]+?))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `([^"]+?)` - Group 3: any 1 or more chars other than `"`, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([A-Z]+/\d[\d.]*)` - Group 4: 1+ uppercase letters, `/` and then 1 digit followed with any 0+ digits or `.` chars
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `\s+` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{3})` - Group 5: three digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.